# Create Excel Array In Formula Text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using a formula that requires an input of a 2D range. I have all the data that should be in the range, but it's currently stored in a row. Is there a way to, within the body of a formula, transform the row into a 2D range so that it can be passed into the formula?

For example, I would like to run something like

```
=Transpose(new_function(A1:A4,2))
```

where new_function(A1:A4,2,2) converts A1:A4 into a 2x2 range.

Comment: You want a formula to move the data? Or handle the data like an array?

Comment: I'd like to handle it like an array.

Comment: So what are you trying to do with a 2x2 array as a whole in a function?

Comment: I'm using an internally created function at my company that requires a 2x2 matrix to work appropriately. I don't have the source code, I don't know exactly how the matrix is being used/manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

`CHOOSE` function can turn any 4 cells in to a 2x2 range, e.g.

`=CHOOSE({1,2;3,4},A1,A2,A3,A4)`

That makes A1 and A2 into the top row and A3 and A4 the bottom row - if you want A1:A2 to be the first column then swap A2 and A3